# How can I use Node.js to post messages to ActiveMQ using its REST interface?

Tags: node.js, forms, http, curl, activemq-classic

I have a STOMP client running in Node.js that is subscribed to a queue in ActiveMQ. When using cURL, I can post messages to the queue (which are immediately consumed by the STOMP client I have running in Node) with the following command:

```
curl -d "body=message" http://sub.dummyhost.net:8161/demo/message/dispatch?type=queue
```

I'm trying to reproduce this POST request using Node.js's request module (https://github.com/request/request) using the following code, which adheres to how we are supposed to send POST requests with application/x-www-form-urlencoded data:

```
request.post({
        url: 'http://sub.dummyhost.net:8161/demo/message/dispatch?type=queue',
        form: {
            body:'message'
        }
    }, 
    function(err, response, body){
      //do something with response
    });
```

In the headers property of the response, I can see the message-id property, which increments each time I make a POST request using the function invocation above. However, when I check on the admin view for the broker itself, I don't see the enqueued and dequeued messages increment (and my STOMP consumer receives nothing, unlike when I make POST requests using cURL). The messages simply do not appear to be published to the queue.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, ActiveMQ didn't like it when I used request.post with the options formatted that way. When I pass in the URL as the first option, it appears to work fine:

```
  var promisifiedPostRequest = Promise.promisify(request.post);
  return promisifiedPostRequest(
    'http://localhost:8080/demo/message/queue1?type=queue', 
    {
      form : {
        body: JSON.stringify(notification),
        AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY : delay
    }
  })
  .then(function(response){
    return response.headers.messageid;
  });
```

I wrote a blog post on REST, Node.js and ActiveMQ here: https://medium.com/@mackplevine/using-activemq-with-node-js-stomp-and-http-b251ce8d995#.4qf53glie

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://sub.dummyhost.net:8161/demo/message/dispatch?type=queue',
  headers: 
   { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
  form: { body: 'message' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

Try this ~